# JQuery - Page jumps back to previous position after scrollTop()

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I want my page to start at the bottom which I try to achieve with this bit:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').scrollTop($(document).height()-$(window).height());
})
```

Now it does what it's supposed to for about 0.5 seconds and then it jumps back to my previous scroll position. I've noticed that it jumps after fully loading the background image.
I have tried several solutions from similar questions like add 'return false;', call 'preventDefault();' or select 'html, body' for the scroll but none worked

any of you have a solution to my problem?

Comment: Isn't `$(document).height()-$(window).height()` equals 0?

Comment: no, the document is the full page whereas the window is the viewport or something. it doesn't really matter though, because even with static values like 300 e.g. it does the same thing

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle demo?

Comment: Is this the final thing to happen or is there some other JS/page loading after this call?

Comment: Which browser and which server-side tech are you using?  This might happen if you're using ASP.Net (webforms) and there's known workaround/way to say don't do this.

Comment: Does it do this if you only have a minimal page (ie just a small amount of html, the background image, jquery and your code).

Comment: I'm running it all locally on a minimal page and so far it's the only js i'm using. it's literally the first thing i wanted to do on my page.
I've tested it on chrome and safari where it does the same thing, as well as firefox, where nothing happens

Comment: I just encountered this same issue in chrome. had a $(document).ready() trigger to scroll to focus element, but then something other seems to load and when that's done it jumps to last known pos.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just this: I tried it in a page with a div 1000px high and filled with garbage tex, it scrolled to the bottom just fine and never jumped back:

```
window.scrollTo ( 0, document.body.scrollHeight );
```

The only way this could fail as far as I can see is if something triggers "ready" again, in which case maybe just do the usual "body onload="scrollBottom()" sort of thing.